# square root of ANY number with arbitrary precision

Tags: python, decimal, precision

How to print the square root of 1 as 1.000 in python? I have seen a lot of similar questions in this cite, but none of them, as I checked, was my question.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, there are several ways. One is:

```
from math import sqrt

print("%.3f" % sqrt(1))
```

Comment: edited to include taking the square root of 1 as opposed to just showing how to print 1 with 3 decimal places.